# How to have multiple cache manager configuration in multiple modules/projects spring cache java

Tags: java, spring-boot, caching, guava

Have two different modules currently Let say Project A and Project B.  Project B imported/used into/in Project A. Currently Project B already have CacheManager.

Project B

```
  public class CacheConfig {

  @Bean 
  public CacheManager cacheManager() {

  // using SimpleCacheManager()

  }
 }
```

But now planed to implement CacheManager in Project A for someother Purpose.

```
class SomeCacheConfig{

@Bean 
public CacheManager someCacheManager(){
 // using SimpleCacheManager() 
}

}
```

While loading application throws below exception.

```
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: No CacheResolver specified, and no unique bean of type CacheManager found. Mark one as primary (or give it the name 'cacheManager') or declare a specific CacheManager to use, that serves as the default one.
```

Can you please help me how to achieve multiple cacheManager in multiple modules/projects.

Comment: Why must it be unique?  Reuse the cache manager you have.

Comment: @duffymo, May be later project B can take it out. so we need new cacheManager in Project A

Comment: would you like to use those 2 different cache managers at the same time ?
or use only one ?

Comment: @javvano, I would like to use two cache Managers

Answer (score 0):

ok then.
put @Primary on the CacheManager bean that will use as default.

```
@Primary
@Bean(name = "primaryCacheManager")
public CacheManager primaryCacheManager() {
    return new SimpleCacheManager();
}


@Bean(name = "myCacheManager")
public CacheManager myCacheManager() {
    return new SimpleCacheManager();
}
```

and when you want to use another one(i.e. not a default), explictly define a name of CacheManager bean with @Qualifier annotation.

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("myCacheManager")
private CacheManager myCacheManager;
```

or if you use [annotation base Spring Cache implementation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/cache/annotation/package-summary.html), you can also define a CacheManager name as property of those annotations

```
@Cacheable(value = "some",cacheManager = "myCacheManager")
public String getSome(){
    return "";
}
```

Comment: thanks for your help. But in this case, we can't use secondary cache Manager. but in my use case i need to use both cache Managers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the CompositeCacheManager implementation provided by Spring (https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/cache/support/CompositeCacheManager.html)

This allows you to compose a list of cache managers.  The composite manager will iterate through the list and get the cache in the first manager it exists in. Please note that "Note: Regular CacheManagers that this composite manager delegates to need to return null from getCache(String) if they are unaware of the specified cache name, allowing for iteration to the next delegate in line. However, most CacheManager implementations fall back to lazy creation of named caches once requested; check out the specific configuration details for a 'static' mode with fixed cache names, if available."

Answer (score 0):

What eventually worked for me as Erik Ahlswede suggested

```
@Bean
public CacheManager cacheManager() {
    return new CompositeCacheManager(
            new ConcurrentMapCacheManager("cacheA") {
                @Override
                protected Cache createConcurrentMapCache(final String name) {
                    return new ConcurrentMapCache(name,
                            CacheBuilder.newBuilder()
                                    .expireAfterWrite(CACHE_TTL_IN_SECONDS, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                                    .maximumSize(MAX_ENTRIES_IN_CACHE)
                                    .build().asMap(), false);
                }
            },
            new ConcurrentMapCacheManager("cacheB") {

                @Override
                protected Cache createConcurrentMapCache(final String name) {
                    return new ConcurrentMapCache(name,
                            CacheBuilder.newBuilder()
                                    .expireAfterWrite(CACHE_TTL_IN_SECONDS, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                                    .maximumSize(MAX_ENTRIES_IN_CACHE)
                                    .build().asMap(), false);
                }
            }
    );
}
```

And then use it with

```
@Cacheable(cacheNames = "someComplicatedAction", cacheManager = "cacheA")
public String someComplicatedAction() {

}
```